# Android TCP Client TextView doesn't Update

Tags: android, multithreading, tcpclient, settext

I'm trying to come up with an android client app that talks with a C#server. I want to update my TextView simultaneously with the server reply message. I'm receiving message with this code

```
public class LogedInActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {
private Spinner meterBrands;
private EditText sayacNo,plcNo;
private String serverMessage="Message is";
private TextView serverStatus; 
private String messageID="120";
private String messageEnd="*?/";
private Thread clientThread;
private static final int SERVERPORT = sss;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "sss";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loged_in);
     serverStatus= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverStatus); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

} 
public void sendMessage(View view) {

     hideSoftKeyboard(this);
    meterBrands= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.brandsSpinner);
    String temp=String.valueOf(meterBrands.getSelectedItem()); 
    if(isValidMeterAndPLC()){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                connectSocket(messageToSend());

                }
            }).start();

    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                connectSocket("1");
                    }
            }).start();
    }


} 


private String connectSocket(String message){ 

String finalText = "";
try { 
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP); 
    Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting..."); 
    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT); 



    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try { 
        Log.d("TCP", "C: Sending: '" + message + "'"); 
        out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new      OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true); 
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));                
        out.println(message);
        String text = "";
        while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
            finalText += text; 
            serverStatus.setText(finalText);
           }


        Log.d("TCP", "C: Sent."); 

        Log.d("TCP", "C: Done.");               

    } catch(Exception e) { 
        Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e); 
    } finally { 
        socket.close(); 
    } 

} catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    Log.e("TCP", "C: UnknownHostException", e); 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    Log.e("TCP", "C: IOException", e); 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}       
return finalText;
} 


public String messageToSend(){
    String infoString;
    sayacNo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sayacNoTextBox);
    plcNo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plcNoTextBox);

    infoString= messageID+"-"+sayacNo.getText()+"-"+meterBrands.getSelectedItem().toString()+"-"+plcNo.getText()+ "-" +messageEnd+"-" ;
    infoString+=checkSum(infoString);

    return infoString;

}
public int checkSum(String str){
    int checkSum=0;
    char [] strChars= str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<strChars.length;i++){
        checkSum+= (int) strChars[i];

    }


    return checkSum;
}
public void messageDisplay(String servermessage){
    serverStatus= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverStatus);
    serverStatus.setText(servermessage);

}  


private boolean isValidMeterAndPLC(){
    boolean check=true;
    int sayacNoInt=0;
    sayacNo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.sayacNoTextBox);
    plcNo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.plcNoTextBox);

    sayacNoInt=Integer.parseInt(sayacNo.getText().toString());
    if(sayacNoInt<100 || sayacNoInt>65530){
        alertbox("Yanlış Sayaç Numarası","Yanlış sayaç numarası girdiniz. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.");
        check=false;

    }
    if(plcNo.getText().toString().length()!=8){
        alertbox("Yanlış PLC Numarası","Yanlış PLC numarası girdiniz. Lütfen tekrar deneyin.");
        check=false;
    }
    return check;

}
protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage)
{

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage(mymessage)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Okay",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, close
            // current activity

        }
    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_loged_in,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    hideSoftKeyboard(this);

    return false;
}

/*back button override.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        alertbox("asasda","5333434");
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
 */
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {

    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}

}
```

However, I can't update my TextView since it's in  a thread

```
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                connectSocket(messageToSend());

                    }
            }).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the sentence where you update with the `runOnUiThread()` statement. For instance:

```
your_context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myTextView.setText("...");
  }
});
```

Anything wrapped in the `runOnUiThread()` statement will actually be run in the main UI `Thread`, so be careful to not add some expensive operations here.

**---- EDIT ----**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    connectSocket(messageToSend());

    // Do whatever you need
    ...

    // Once you want to update your TextView...
    final myTextView tv = (TextView) your_context.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    final String myText = "whatever";

    your_context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        myTextView.setText(myText);
      }
    });
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: I have 2 problems with that. 1) if I do it where I use my connectSocket method, I got an exception that says you can't make network connection in UIthread.
2) if I do it where I settext (which is in connectSocket method) it says the text should be final.

Comment: But simply put inside the `run()` method of `runOnUiThread` the sentence where you assign the text to the `TextView` via `.setText()`, nothing more! As I wrote, this will be run in the UI thread, so you have to put here just the necessary. This way you won't have he network connection inside and you won't get the exception.

Comment: Simply declare the `text` variable as `final String text = ...`.

Comment: I'm quit new in android and updated my question. Can you please show me where and how ?

Comment: Maybe [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) would fit better.

Comment: I added an example that could fit what you're doing. However, if you're new, you probably might want to try what @enrmarc said.

Comment: nKn thanks for your effort but it doesn't work either. I got source not found exception.

Comment: On what line from the above?

Comment: here 
    final String finalText = text; 
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      serverStatus.setText(  finalText);
                    }
                  });
                }

Comment: I've fixed the problem by your advices nKn thanks a lot